# Deadlock with select and multiple sockets in single process

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, select, deadlock

I'm working in a Linux environment on a layered infrastructure where each layer is a stand alone process which communicates with the layers above or below it using some kind of socket connection. It could be UNIX, TCP, UDP, the protocol doesn't matter. To make this scheme work, any process that is not the top most or bottom most layer must have both a server and a client socket. We are using a homespun library that creates a thread for the run time of each connection (i.e. send and receive) which is fed by mutex guarded queues. The code in this library uses a select() call and fd sets to monitor each socket, and works perfectly when a connections are isolated in their own processes. However, when we try to use two or more threaded socket handlers in a single process we're facing what I believe is deadlock on the select() calls, but I'm not sure.

The test case we're using (just a simple .cpp module, not a formal unit test) will continually send but never receive.  What it should be doing is echoing messages that either connection handler is sending each other. It's important to know that the handlers are *NOT* communicating over a socket but are able to pass messages within the memory of the process (made possible by a 'routing' algorithm running in thread 1). Thread 1 is also constantly sending messages to be sent out by either server via mutex guarded queues, and it is not dead locking on these mutexes.

Here's what I can see with the debugger

```
(gdb) info threads
  3 Thread 0xb7525b70 (LWP 5001)  0xb7fe2424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  2 Thread 0xb7d26b70 (LWP 5000)  0xb7fe2424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
* 1 Thread 0xb7d276d0 (LWP 4999)  0xb7f64370 in std::string::length() const () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
```

This isn't an issue of two threads dead locking on the same socket because they are not sharing a socket or trying to communicate over one. It appears to me that the competing `select()` calls are causing the process to suspend over and over again, so neither connection handler is ever able to write outgoing messages to the socket. I've tried setting the time out for both connections to 1 usec to no effect.

ascii map:

```
thread 2                                 thread 1               thread 3
[[server socket a] <-> [server a]] <-> [intermediary] <-> [[server b] <-> [server socket b]]
```

I can post code from our library (we're planning on a FOSS release anyway) if more detail would be useful. If any one can positively identify this as deadlock, can they take another step further and recommend a work around?

Thanks!

Comment: select() blocks. It can't cause a deadlock by itself. If you have a deadlock it is far more likely to arise from your homespun library's semaphores. Check that they are always acquired and released in the same order.